# Read a C-type string from Go

Tags: c, string, opengl, go

I am trying to write a simple OpenGL application in Go and would like to read the OpenGL Version from the driver. I am using this function:

http://godoc.org/github.com/chsc/gogl/gl21#GetString

which is a wrapper function for

```
const GLubyte* glGetString( GLenum name);
```

### This code:

```
fmt.Println(gl.GetString(gl.RENDERER))
fmt.Println(*gl.GetString(gl.VERSION))
```

outputs

```
0x4708ae0
50
```

The output is probably a C-type string, pointer to the first byte of the string. How can I convert the output from the GetString function into a normal go string?

---

## Solution:

The package provided the right converter function, it is just not really obvious:

```
fmt.Println( gl.GoStringUb( gl.GetString( gl.RENDERER )))
```

#### General approach: (if the package wouldn't provide a *Ubyte to string conversion function)

```
pointer := unsafe.Pointer(gl.GetString(gl.RENDERER))
str := C.GoString( (*C.char)(pointer) )
fmt.Println(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you linked provides a function `GoStringUb` that does the trick:

```
render := gl.GoStringUb(gl.GetString(gl.RENDERER))
version := gl.GoStringUb(gl.GetString(gl.VERSION))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I got it to work and updated the question
the library wrapper was generated by a program that downloads the OpenGL spec and translates it to go functions, thats why it probably lacks go strings..

Comment: @mbert Please disregard this answer. I found out a better way.

Comment: @mbert Updated the answer to reflect the actual way to solve this problem.

Comment: thank you, thats of course a cleaner solution, but they really should put a hint to this function in their documentation for GetString..